# Ember hasMany relationship save on create

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm trying to create an ember data record with a hasMany relationship from a POJO, and it's been remarkably difficult.  This is using ember-concurrency (hence the task and yield syntax.

```
  saveEntry: task(function* (obj){
      let entry = yield this.model.get('entries').createRecord({
        groupId: obj.objectID,
        name: obj.name,
        ...

      }).save();
      obj.owner_ids.forEach((user_id) => {
        this.store.findRecord('user', user_id).then((user) => {
          entry.get('owners').pushObject(user);
          entry.save();
        });
      })
   }).drop();
```

So the tough bits are the 'obj.owner_ids', which is an array of user_ids.  I add each to the array, but then need to save after every pushObject or it doesn't work.  And even when it does work, it is throwing a bunch of network errors (probably due to race conditions on the save).  There **must** be a better way, but I haven't found it.

Comment: What options does your API provide for saving has-many relationships? What request do you expect to save those relationships? Does your API implements [JSON:API specification](https://jsonapi.org/)?

Comment: I control the API (which is spec'd to JSONAPI) so I can do whatever is necessary.  Ideally I'd save it all on one request, but what I'm mostly trying to avoid is saving it each time I addd a `user_id`.

Comment: Don't have time for a full answer right now but as a hint: You could include the relationship on creation. You may need to customize [`shouldSerializeHasMany` method](https://api.emberjs.com/ember-data/3.12/classes/JSONAPISerializer/methods/shouldSerializeHasMany?anchor=shouldSerializeHasMany) of the Serializer cause by default many-to-one relationships are not serialized. You may want to keep that behavior for updates to prevent conflicts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what `this.model` represents in your code, but you could try fetching all of the users you need and then attaching them at the time you create and save like:

```
import { all } from 'rsvp';

saveEntry: task(function* (obj){
  let users = obj.owner_ids.map(userId => this.store.findRecord('user', user_id));

  let promises = this.model.get('entries').createRecord({
    groupId: obj.objectID,
    name: obj.name,
    owners: users,
    ...
  }).save()

  // all() waits for an an array of promises to return
  yield all(promises);
}).drop();
```

Comment: Thanks, this gets me half-way there.  But this returns an array of promises, as opposed to the results of those promises, and so it fails -- and despite having worked with Ember for more than two years I still am flummoxed with how to return promise results when in arrays.  I'm so close to giving up on Ember....

Comment: I modified my answer to use the RSVP.all function to deal with that array. Hope that helps. Sorry you're frustrated with Ember. The bad news is this kind of promise stuff is difficult everywhere.

Comment: Your response does the best job in answering the question, although I have to admin the overall solution eludes me...